# how to compile python-debuginfo from source?

Tags: python, gdb

I'm current debugging a Python script under redhat with gdb. As the default Python 2.6.6 is somewhat outdated, I installed 2.7.11 in the system and run my scripts with Python 2.7.11.

However, when I start learning about Python debugging, I find that I am unable to get a python-debuginfo package which is needed by gdb. The system default debug package is 2.6.6 and I don't know how to create a debuginfo package for version 2.7.11

I'm quite skilled in writing rpm spec files. But I did not find an open-source rpm spec file for python-debuginfo package either.

Could someone help me?

Comment: why can't you debug the Python script with `pdb`? You need `gdb` to debug `python` interpreter.

Comment: @NizamMohamed I need to attach a debugger onto a running process, but with pdb it is a bit difficult

Comment: recompile python with debugging symbols `-g` for `gccc`.